# Grub doesn't resume Windows 10 hibernation

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub, hibernate

Recently i've received a Dell Inspiron 7501 laptop, and i've installed on it ubuntu 18.04 alongside the preinstalled windows 10. The issue is that windows hibernation works perfectly when the windows boot manager is selected as the first boot option (from the BIOS), but when the grub is used to start Windows no program is restored from the hibernation. From the windows event viewer i can see 2 events describing this error:

- Windows experienced an unexpected shutdown
- Windows could not resume from hibernation (error code 0xC0000004)

I've tried many fixes online (from bios updates to driver updates and so on) but nothing seems to work. One last detail, one friend of mine has the same laptop and installed ubuntu in the exact same way i did, but he doesn't experience this issue.

Comment: Modern PC with UEFI BIOS does not require to have a bootloader that allows "cross" booting. Just use the UEFI boot select functions and keep both OS separate.

Comment: @Robert But i'd need each time to open up the bios and select it from there... or do you mean something else?

Comment: Every BIOS I know has a quick boot menu primarily to boot from CD or USB stick. In this menu also the regular UEFI boot entries like Windows and Linux are present.